# How to access a variable from a void return function in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am contributing to a rather large project. I have written a piece of code and I am calling an external function that carries out a bunch of calculations.

I need `external_function()` to run through completely, but I also need the value of a specific variable (a double) that is calculated during `external_function()`. I would like to store or at least use the value of this variable in `my_function()`. Is this possible? Something along the lines of

```
double my_variable = external_function(external_variable);
```

Note the code looks like this:

```
void external_function()
{
    double d;
    // perform calculations on d
}

void my_function()
{
    ...
    external_function();
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, `external_function` does not return anything, it just does calculations and prints some output. As the entire code of the project is already rather complex, I would like to change as little as possible in the part of the code that has not been written by me. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: If it's really necessary, the quick and dirty solution would be to just throw in a variable that has a larger scope than both the functions so that it can be used.

Comment: I've [updated your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45473805/3) to hopefully better reflect what it is you're trying to do. If this does not accurately reflect your problem, feel free to [edit] the question to add clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here you have code like the following:

```
void external_function()
{
    double d;
    // perform calculations on d
    ...
    // print d
    std::cout << d;
}

void my_function()
{
    ...
    external_function();
    ...
}
```

I'll assume `external_function` takes no parameters, but it really doesn't matter if it does.

You can change `external_function` by modifying the return type to `double`:

```
double external_function()
{
    double d;
    // perform calculations on d
    ...
    // print d
    std::cout << d;
    return d;
}
```

The function can still be called safely like so:

```
external_function();
```

Without catching the return value, so there is no need to update other uses of it. Some static code analysers might hassle you about ignoring the return value of a function, but you can probably write an exception for them if you want.

This now means you can call it like so:

```
double value = external_function();
```

Your second option would be to pass an optional parameter to `external_function()`:

```
void external_function(double* out = nullptr)
{
    double d;
    // perform calculations on d
    ...
    // print d
    std::cout << d;
    if (out)
        *out = d;
}
```

The same thing goes: callers can still call this function without changing the way they call it:

```
 external_function();
```

But it means you can now call it like this:

```
double value = 0.0;
external_function(&value);
// value now contains the same value as d
```

Answer (score 1):

If the function `external_function` returns a double, then yes, you can store that in a double as you have shown in the question.  That will be perfectly fine.

If the `double` variable you are talking about is a local variable in that function that is not returned or stored in a variable passed to the function by reference, then you do not have any way of fetching that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But sorry, I should have said that, `external_function` does not return anything. It only performs calculations and prints the output. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to store the value of `external_function(external_variable)` in a variable.

Be sure to check that the return type of `external_function` is `double` and, therefore, returns a double value. You will need to code it like this :

```
    double external_function() {
           double returnedValue;
           // your code here
           cout << calculationOutputValue << endl;
           return returnedValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class member variable of double type. 
Assign the calculated value of "d" to the member variable.

Now you can use this member variable in any method of your class.

or
You can pass a reference parameter from your calling method and assign the value of "d" in the externalfunction.
Eg:

```
externalFunction(double &updatedValue)
{
//do calculation of d
updatedValue =d;
}

void my_function()
{
double value;
externalFuntcion(value);
//now value will have the value of d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mode 1 : Use `void external_function()`, adding parameter.**

```
void external_function(double* pValue)
{
    *pValue = external_value;
    // operation of external_value
    // external_value = 142.14
}
```

Get result

```
void call_function()
{
    double pValue = 0.0;
    external_function(&pValue);
    cout<<pValue<<endl;
}
```

Result : `142.14`

**Mode 2 : Use no parameter function, modifying return type of function.**

```
double external_function()
{
    // do something you want...
    // external_value = 142.14;
    return external_value;
}
```

Get result

```
void call_function()
{
    double pValue;
    pValue = external_function();
    cout<<pValue<<endl;
}
```

Result : `142.14`